# Eclipse C build error symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors, symbols

I can't figure out what im missing. I have a main method but it's still not building. Here's my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 // #include <conio.h>



int main(){
float length, width, area;
printf("Enter length of Rectangle\n");
scanf("%f", &length);
printf("Enter width of Rectangle\n");
scanf("%f", &width);
/* Area of Rectangle = Length X Width */
area = length * width;
printf("Area of Rectangle : %0.4f\n", area);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Also im getting "make: *** [LabZero] Error 1" LabZero is the name of the project folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the other error is?

Answer (score 0):

`getch()` is in curses.h, so you'll need to include it. In the code above you could just remove the `getch()` call, too.

The error message you posted is just `make` telling you the build failed; there should be more errors before that, from the compiler and/or linker, which should give you a better idea of *why* it failed.

Comment: removed getch() and the error is still present unfortunately.

Comment: What error? Read the second paragraph of my answer; what you posted doesn't actually tell you anything, we need to know what precedes make failing.

Comment: Here's the full content in my console  :  "make all 
Building target: LabZero
Invoking: MacOS X C Linker
gcc  -o "LabZero"  ./rectangle.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [LabZero] Error 1"